# 2d collisions in javascript

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am making a game using p5.js and in that game there is a player and obstacles. Both of these will be simple rectangles. I am able to use simple collision detection to see if they are overlapping. What I want to do is when the player hits the obstacle it stops like physics in real life. I currently have a system that treats the sides of the obstacle as four different obstacles but it isn't working well can someone give any advice on tweaks that I could do to make it work better.

```
    if(walls[i].x < p1.x + p1.width/2 &&
        walls[i].x + 5 > p1.x && 
        walls[i].y + walls[i].height + p1.height/2 > p1.y &&
        walls[i].y < p1.y + p1.height/2){
            p1.x = walls[i].x-p1.width/2
        }
        if(walls[i].x < p1.x + p1.width/2 &&
            walls[i].x + walls[i].width + p1.width/2 > p1.x && 
            walls[i].y + p1.height/2 > p1.y &&
            walls[i].y < p1.y + p1.height/2){
                p1.y = walls[i].y-p1.height/2
            }
    if(walls[i].x < p1.x + p1.width/2 &&
     walls[i].x + walls[i].width + p1.width/2 > p1.x &&
    p1.y > walls[i].y + walls[i].height - 5 &&
    p1.y - p1.height/2 < walls[i].y + walls[i].height){
    p1.y = walls[i].y + walls[i].height + p1.width/2
     }
     if(p1.x > walls[i].x + walls[i].width - 5 &&
        p1.x - p1.width/2 < walls[i].x + walls[i].width && 
        walls[i].y + walls[i].height + p1.height/2 > p1.y &&
        walls[i].y < p1.y + p1.height/2){
            p1.x = walls[i].x + walls[i].width + p1.width/2
        }
```

I will post all of the code if someone wants me to but it is somewhat long

Comment: Can you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Yeah it might just be easier for me to post the whole thing is that ok

Comment: Could you better use a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) snippet? You can also insert snippet here in StackOverflow (7th icon in the question editor)

Comment: This might be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ also to avoid implementing the collision yourself [p5play](https://molleindustria.github.io/p5.play/) is pretty straig hforward but not really focused on performances and [matter.js](https://brm.io/matter-js/) is a complete physic engine which might be useful but a little harder to get your hands on.

Comment: I ended up using matter.js and it is working great thank you for all of your help

Comment: @JakeGrubba if you found a solution, I suggest posting a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to help others with the same problem as you who wind up in this thread in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the package I use instead of importing a heavyweight physics library like matter.js:

https://github.com/bmoren/p5.collide2D

It is perfect for detecting collisions if you want to program in your own reactions instead of following matter.js's physical estimations. I mostly use it to avoid doing ugly manual collision calculations (especially with irregular polygons).

Comment: I might try that if the matter.js solution doesn't work or doesn't run smoothly.